# How to map persistent objects to DTO?

Tags: java, dictionary, dto, persistent

How to map persistent object to DTO? 
So that no additional behavior is taken. I know it is quite common and easy, but many people - many opinions, what are the best approaches?

(talking about Java)

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you mean - is this a conceptual question or are you simply looking for an O/R mapper?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a object mapper like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Orika it also support hetrogenous mapping with ease coding.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) (disclaimer: I'm the original author of this project). MapStruct generates mapping code at compile-time which is thus fast and type-safe, i.e. you don't have any runtime dependencies and get feedback about incompatible mappings at build time, e.g. within your IDE.