# Object mapper vs Object wrapper

Tags: oop, automapper, data-access-layer, objectmapper

I would appreciate a little help here...

Lets say that in an application we have a Data Layer and a Business Logic Layer. In the DAL we have the following entity:

```
public class Customer {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
}

public class Address {
    public string Street {get; set;}
}
```

In the BLL we have the following POCOs:

```
public class CustomerDto {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<AddressDto> Addresses {get; set;}
}

public class AddressDto {
    public string Street {get; set;}
}
```

The entities in the DAL are populated with a ligth-weight ORM and retrieve from the BLL using a repository. Ex:

```
public class CustomerInformationService {

    private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository {get; set;}
    public CustomerInformationService (ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
         _repository = repository;
    }
    public class CustomerDto Get(int id)
    {
         var customerEntity = _repository.Get(id);

         var customerDto = /* SOME TRANSFORMATION HERE */

         return customerDTO;
    }
}
```

My questions is about the /* SOME TRANSFORMATION HERE */ part. There is a discussion in our team about how to do the "mapping".

One approach is to use a mapper either an automapper or a manual mapping.
The second approach is to use sort of like a wrapper around Entity and reference the DTO in order to save a copying operation between object. Something like this:

```
public class CustomerDto
{
     private IEntity _customerEntity;

     public IEntity CustomerEntity { get {return _customerEntity;}}

     public CustomerDto(IEntity customerEntity)
     {
          _customerEntity = customerEntity;
     }

     public string Name 
     { 
          get { return _customerEntity.Name; }
     }
     public ICollection<Address> Addresses 
     { 
          get { return _customerEntity.Addresses; }
     }
}
```

The second approach feels a little weird to me because _customerEntity.Addresses feels like a leak (_customerEntity's reference) between my DAL and my BLL but I am not sure.

Are there any advantages/disavantages of using one approach over the other one?

Additional info: We usually pull a max. of 1000 records at a time that would need to be transform between Entity and DTO.

Comment: If you're going to use the wrapper approach, you might as well just use the entities and forget about using the dto objects. You're not buying anything with the wrapper, but are adding in tight coupling and another dependency.

Comment: @dbugger - thanks for you answer. Which dependency do you mean? The BLL would always know the interfaces from DAL regardless of we use a mapper or a wrapper to create the DTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mentioned your "ligth-weight ORM". I will answer in two sections.

## If you are using ORM that creates proxies

You should avoid exposing Entities outside certain boundary. ORMs like NHibernate/EF implement lazy loading based on proxies. If you expose Entities to application/UI layer, you will have little control over ORM behavior. This may lead to many unexpected issues and debugging will also very difficult.

Wrapping Entities in DTOs will gain nothing. You are accessing Entities anyway.

Using DTOs and mapping them with some mapper tool like AutoMapper is good solution here.

## If you are using ORM that does not create proxies

Do NOT use DTOs, directly use your Entities. DTOs are useful and recommended here in many cases. But the example you given in question does not need DTOs at all.

In case you choose to use DTOs, wrapping Entities in DTOs does not make sense. If you want to use Entity anyway, why wrap it? Again, tool like AutoMapper could help.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40720883/5779732) question. It's bit different; I am asking **Yes/No** and you are asking **How**. But still it will help you.

Comment: Thanks A_J. It took a while to settle the discussion but the distinction you made between ORM with proxies and without proxies helped us a lot. In our case, the ORM was not generating proxies but the Entities needed special attributes in order for the ORM to map them. Since we didn't want to expose this attributes in other layers, we ended up wrapping them in DTO and using an automapper.

Answer (score 0):

I bet for the *service layer approach*. Basically because something that looks like a business object or *domain object* has nothing to do with *DTOs*.

And, indeed, you and your team should use *AutoMapper* instead of repeating the same code tons of times which will consist in setting some properties from A to B, A to C, C to B...

Comment: In fact, for me, manual mapping in a large code base can be only a symptom of the [proud developer](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/anti-design-patterns/proud-developer) syndrome!